# Determine if this object is doubled

Tags: java, linked-list

```
    interface ILoString {
}

class MtLoString implements ILoString {

}

class ConsLoString implements ILoString {
    String first;
    ILoString rest;

    ConsLoString(String first, ILoString rest) {
        this.first = first;
        this.rest = rest;
    }


    
}
```

Need to design the method isDoubledList that determines if this list contains pairs of identical strings, that is, the first and second strings are the same, the third and fourth are the same, the fifth and sixth are the same, etc.

I want to use

```
 boolean isDoubledList(){ return this.first.equals(second item in list) && this.rest.isDoubledList() }
```

but do not know how to extract pairs of items out of list at a time without overlapping

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: boolean isDoubled();

Comment: I fixed my question

Comment: Use "instanceof Double" to query the object